# How to update magento 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9

Can yo please help us to update our old version of Magento in Simple steps as after Searching I tried and there are errors in My website.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Download magento 1.9.2.3

**NOTE : Disable cache, compilation, remove cache and js merge, remove var/cache folder.**

Extract all the files and copy and replace with your magento (1.9.1.0 - **please take backup before doing that**) .

If there will be any modification in core files that you will get the issues. so be careful and take the backup.

Also, there may be issue with permission.

Now, If you get the error you need to fix them one by one.

Tips, Try to disable some extension first, then update those extension or fix the issue of that.

You need to give permission for some blocks as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrade Roadmap for CE 1.9.1.0 from 1.9.2.3**

1. Take a backup of current database and current 1.9.1.0 code. place maintenance.flag file inside root folder your current magento.
2. Download latest magento or whatever you need a version of magento from the https://magento.com/tech-resources/download
3. Now abstract latest magento folder to your current directory.
4. Now go to app/etc/local.xml.Edit database details their.put your database username and password and database name.
5. Remove maintenance.flag file and check the site in the browser. it is done.
6. Remove / cache, /session folder from var directory.

   And check.